# Show colorbox close button when Flash is disabled only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I am looking to only display the js.colorbox close button when Flash is disabled (not installed/uninstalled) on the window.  I don't need to display the close button when Flash is enabled as there is a close button on the swf object.

Any help would be appreciated as Im stuck.

Cheers Lou

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HTML file which will contain your flash file. To embed it use SWFObject.

SWFObject has a callback function which can tell if flash object has been successfully embedded.

So your code may be similar to this:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
                    "fileName.swf", 
                    replaceElemIdStr, 
                    widthStr, 
                    heightStr, 
                    swfVersionStr, 
                    xiSwfUrlStr, 
                    flashvarsObj, 
                    parObj, 
                    attObj, 
                    callbackFn);

function callbackFn(e)
{
    if (e.success)
    {
        //flash is there
        //do not show close button
        //use jQuery to alter css
    }
    else
    {
        //ooops, no flash file
        //do show close button
    }
}
```